# Laravel cant sync a many to many relationship

Tags: php, database, laravel, relational-database, eloquent

I am am trying to save to my database, and as part of that save I am trying to sync my many to many relationship, however I am getting the following error from my API,

```
"BadMethodCallException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::sync()"
```

I would have thought that this is because the relationships I have in my model are not many to many so cant be synced, but they look correct to me,

```
class Organisation extends Eloquent {

//Organsiation __has_many__ users (members)
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('is_admin');
}

//Organisation __has_many__ clients
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Client');
}

//Organisation __has_many__ teams
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Team');
}

//Organisation __has_many__ projects
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Project');
}
```

}

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

public function organisations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Organisation')->withPivot('is_admin');
}
```

}

I am running the sync after a successful save,

```
if(isset($members)) {
    $organisation->users()->sync($members);
}
```

and members is certainly set. The organsisation is created in the following way,

```
public function create()
{
    //
    $postData = Input::all();

    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
    );  

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validation->fails()) {

        return Response::json( $validation->messages()->first(), 500);

    } else {

        $organisation = new Organisation;

        // Save the basic organistion data.
        $organisation->name = $postData['name'];
        $organisation->information = $postData['information'];
        $organisation->type = 'organisation';

        /*
        * Create an array of users that can used for syncinng the many-to-many relationship
        * Loop the array to assign admins to the organisation also.
        */
        if(isset($postData['members'])) {

            $members = array();

            foreach($postData['members'] as $member) {
                if(isset($postData['admin'][$member['id']]) && $postData['admin'][$member['id']] == "on") {
                    $members[$member['id']] = array(
                        'is_admin' => 1
                    );
                } else {
                    $members[$member['id']] = array(
                        'is_admin' => 0
                    );
                }
            }

        }

        /*
        * Create an array of clients so we can sync the relationship easily
        *
        */
        if(isset($postData['clients'])) {

            $clients = array();
            foreach($postData['clients'] as $client) {
                $clients[] = $client['id'];
            }

        }

        /*
        * Create an array of teams so we can sync the relationship easily
        *
        */

        if(isset($postData['teams'])) {

            $teams = array();

            foreach($postData['teams'] as $team) {
                $teams[] = $team['id'];
            }

        }

        /*
        * Create an array of projects so we can sync the relationship easily
        *
        */
        if(isset($postData['projects'])) {

            $projects = array();

            foreach($postData['projects'] as $project) {
                $projects[] = $project['id'];
            }
        }


        if( $organisation->save() ) {

            if(isset($members)) {
                $organisation->users()->sync($members);
            }

            if(isset($teams)) {
                $organisation->teams()->sync($teams);
            }

            if(isset($teams)) {
                $organisation->clients()->sync($clients);
            }

            if(isset($projects)) {
                $organisation->projects()->sync($projects);
            }

            $organisation->load('users');
            $organisation->load('teams');
            $organisation->load('clients');
            $organisation->load('projects');

            return Response::make($organisation, 200);

        } else {

            return Response::make("Something has gone wrong", 500);

        }



    }

}
```

Comment: You should show what is `$organisation` here. How you create it.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking a while for the problem and I didn't see any (I was looking at first `sync` as you suggested) but I looked again and I think the problem is not syncing users here. Probably the problem is:

```
if(isset($projects)) {
   $organisation->projects()->sync($projects);
}
```

You are trying to use `sync` on 1 to many relationship because you defined it this way:

```
return $this->hasMany('Project');
```

So either change `hasMany` here into `belongsToMany` if it's many to many relationship (that's probably the case) or don't use `sync` here for `$projects` because it works only for many to many relationship.